# Axios response is undefined, console log in catch is displayed

Tags: reactjs

In my login page, I use axios to send a response to server in a separate function and I use a callback to set the Login component state in the main Login component. The trouble is, I get a `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined`. A `console.log` in the catch shows me `TypeError: onSucceed is not a function` (`onSucceed` is the callback function in case of `Status 200`). But my `console.log` in `.then` is also displayed. What the hell? Are my callbacks really wrong?

My Request function:

```
import axios from "axios";

export const loginRequest = (state, onSucceed, onCatch) => {
    axios.post("api/auth", { "email": state.email, "password": state.password })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.status === 200) onSucceed(response);
        }).catch(exception => {
            console.log(exception);
            if (exception.response.status === 400) onCatch();
        });
}
```

Here's my form submit handle:

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    if (state.password === "" || state.email === "") {
        event.preventDefault();
        setState({
            ...state,
            emptyForm: true
        })
        return;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    loginRequest(state, props, 
        (response) => {
            props.loggingIn(response.data.userName, response.data.name);
            setCookie({
                userName: response.data.userName,
                fullName: response.data.name, expireDays: 0.125, isLoggedIn: true
            });
            history.push("/");
        },
        () => {
        setState({ ...state, badCredentials: true });
});
```

Comment: Start trying to pass the correct parameters to your loginRequest in your form submit handler. Remove that "props" from params and see what happens next.

Comment: `const loginRequest = (state, onSucceed, onCatch)` but you are doing `loginRequest(state, props, () => {}, () => {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onSuccess` function is missing before you call it, as the error points out, and that's why your `then` block throws an error, which passes the execution to the `catch` block (in which the log shows exactly that this is the error). As for `TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined`, this is probably encountered in the `catch` block, where you try to test the condition for `exception.response.status === 400`, `exception.response` might be undefined, so trying to access `status` of undefined would cause the application to crush.

Also noticed that on your submit handler function, you call `loginRequest` with the wrong arguments. There's 4 arguments provided instead of 3 that are expected (state, onSuccess, onCatch). Try to remove `props` from the arguments you pass to the function.